# Multiply NaN or Inf with 0 and get 0

Tags: c++, nan

I have a set of values `a[i]`.

Then I compute

```
for(...){
  b[i] = log(a[i]);
}
```

Then I sum up

```
for(...){
  s += c[i] * b[i];
}
```

That's no problem so far.

BUT for some `i` my `a[i]` may be zero and lead to `b[i] = log(0) = -Inf`. For these `i`, `c[i]` is also zero - those are some invalid data points. But `zero*-Inf` seems to give `NaN`, and my sum is messed up...

Is there a way to always have `c[i] * b[i]` = 0 when `c[i]` is = 0?

The only way I see is to set all zero `a[i]` to a small non-zero value or to check for zero, but there might be better solutions.

I use C++ and `std` math functions, but I'm looking for a method which works as generally as possible.

Comment: browse the array and replace all NaN by 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short:

```
for(...){
  double tmp = c[i] * b[i];
  s += (tmp == tmp) ? tmp : 0;
}
```

`0 * Inf` is `NaN` by definition (IEEE 754 standard) - so you can't change that behaviour.

The 'textbook' way of testing if a number is nan is to compare with itself, eg:

```
if (x != x)
    std::cout << "x is nan" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "x is not nan" << std::endl;
```

This relies on the fact that `NaN` is not equal to anything, including itself. (again by definition).

C++11 introduces [is_nan](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) which is more readable, and if you don't have C++11 I'd recommend writing your own like

```
bool isnan(double arg) { return arg != arg; }
```

In fact, `NaN` does not compare true to anything, so the following will all work:

```
if (x < y) std::cout << "x is not nan" << std::endl;
if (x > y) std::cout << "x is not nan" << std::endl;
if (x <= y) std::cout << "x is not nan" << std::endl;
if (x >= y) std::cout << "x is not nan" << std::endl;
```

The reason behind this surprising behavior ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)) is that being able to code using the above conditions to filter out `NaN` makes for very straightforward code, and also makes `NaN` a suitable sentinel for `not set` or `unknown` values.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (...) {
  s += c[i] * (std::isinf(b[i]) ? 1 : b[i]);
}

for (...) {
  s += (c[i] == 0 ? 0 : c[i] * b[i]);
}
```

Comment: To fully answer the question, you need isinf, not isnan

Comment: You are right, I fixed that. And I also added another option which doesn't require isinf :-)

Comment: The second option simply circumvent the problem. Nice.

Comment: As long as c[i] is an integer, which I assume (although it's not explicitly stated) that it is.

Comment: `c[i]` can be a float - no problem - so long as it is not the result of a calculation. (If it is result of a calculation is may be extremely close to zero but not quite equal, which may not be what is required). Since the OP stated `c[i] == 0` represents missing data, it seems likely the zero is read from a file (for example) or in some other way we can be sure it is exactly zero.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign `b[i]` you can use the following construction:

```
b[i] = (a[i] == 0) ? 0 : log(a[i]);
```

Or in case of floating point comparison (Read the comments why this solution also works for current question, but may be not good idea at all):

```
b[i] = (fabs(a[i]) < DBL_EPSILON) ? 0 : log(a[i]);
```

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what DBL_EPSILON is.  In any case that comparison to DBL_EPSILON is a very bad idea.  the original comparison to zero was fine.  But for the original question, comparing `c[i]` to 0 made more sense than comparing `a[i]`, because when `a[i]==0 && c[i]!=0` the result can't be correct and you probably want NaN or INF.

Comment: This does what the questioner asked (`c[i] * b[i] = 0` when `c[i] is = 0`) but probably not what they want: as pointed out if `b[i]` is `nan` and `c[i]` should be zero but isn't due to rounding errors the sum will still be `nan`. Using `DBL_EPSILON` won't fix this, because the error in a floating point calculation may be arbitrarily large depending on the calculation.

 Note that if you _know_ `c[i]` will be zero (because it was set to zero, and not as a result of a calculation that may be only close to zero) this answer is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the test for a number being infinite in cmath; something like:

```
s += (c[i] == 0 && std::isinf(b[i])) ? 0 : c[i] * b[i];
```

Comment: To fully answer the question, you need isinf, not isnan